# chessboard pattern data from IR sensor MLX90640

Tags: sensor

I'm developing an algorithm using esp32 with [MLX90640](https://www.melexis.com/en/product/MLX90640/Far-Infrared-Thermal-Sensor-Array) IR sensor.

After I read data frames and calculated the temperature, the temperature values see a  strong chessboard-pattern style. See images below (raw temperature data)

[image: temperature visualize]

Part of measured values:
[image]
I marked some obviouslly abnormal points.

And here is my core measuring code :

```
    int expectFrame = 0;
    int subPagesRead = 0;
    while (true) 
    {
        while (subPagesRead < 2) {
            vTaskDelay(250 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
            status = MLX90640_GetFrameData(0x33, mlx90640Frame);
            if (status != expectFrame) {
                continue;
            }
            expectFrame = 1 - expectFrame;
            subPagesRead++;
            float tr = MLX90640_GetTa(mlx90640Frame, &mlx90640) - TA_SHIFT;
            MLX90640_CalculateTo(mlx90640Frame, &mlx90640, emissivity, tr, mlx90640To);
        }
        // output mlx90640To
        memset(mlx90640Frame, 0, sizeof(mlx90640Frame));
        memset(mlx90640To, 0, sizeof(mlx90640To));
        subPagesRead = 0;
    }
```

Am I measuing in a wrong way? Or any other possible reasons?

(This frame is calculated at 4Hz refresh rate on a esp32 chip)

Comment: Have you made or enable a NUC?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the sensor specifically but to help with the question it'd be good to know what you're expecting. What did you have it pointed at when you saw the pattern shown? I'm also wondering if it requires a calibration frame where it's shown a black body (or other surface of known emissivity) emitter at a known temperature like traditional thermal cameras.

Comment: I would look at overflow (the end of a byte partially written to the next one) during the reading of the sensor (SPI/I2c/serial issue) or conversion issue.

Comment: Maybe check the endianness as well

Comment: @hooskworks. The specification says the sensor has an accuracy of +/- 1 °C. But see my measurement values, the temperature of neighboring pixels can have a big difference, which is where I think there is something wrong. And this pattern is always there whereever I point at. Finally, calibration data is stored in EEPROM, which is fetched and used to calculate temperatures when new frame available.

Comment: @Damien Actually the API of sensor operations is [open-source](https://github.com/melexis/mlx90640-library/).

Comment: @FMashiro since I use the official API of fetching raw data and converting to temperature. This issue is probably not related to endianness or overflow/conversion issues.

Comment: Hey guys, with the advice of adding capacitors between vdd and ground from github issue, the data looks quite normal now. Thanks for your help, too.

Comment: Excellent. Might be worth submitting that as an answer to this question rather than a comment with a link so it can be accepted and is easier for others to find if they have the same issue.

Comment: @hooskworks Now added. Also thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 3):

So I opened an issue in the [official github API library repo](https://github.com/melexis/mlx90640-library/issues/51). And @LBuydens at Github pointed out the lack of power decoupling capacitors could be a reason leading to this striped pattern. Then I read the [data sheet](https://www.melexis.com/-/media/files/documents/datasheets/mlx90640-datasheet-melexis.pdf) again, and found this paragraph at the very end:

> Power supply decoupling capacitor is needed as with most integrated circuits. MLX90640Bxx is a mixed-signal device with
>   sensors, small signal analog part, digital part and I/O circuitry. In order to keep the noise low power supply switching noise
>   needs to be decoupled. High noise from external circuitry can also affect noise performance of the device. In many
>   applications a 100nF SMD plus 1μF ceramic capacitors close to the Vdd and Vss pins would be a good choice. It should be
>   noted that not only the trace to the Vdd pin needs to be short, but also the one to the Vss pin. Using MLX90640Bxx with
>   short pins improves the effect of the power supply decoupling.

With the help of our hardware engineer adding these two capacitors, I finally got a normal frame. Though small temperature difference still exists (likely < 0.5 degrees), it can be ignored.

[image: Temperature measured now]